# lftp fails on cPanel cron

Tags: cron, cpanel, lftp

I have a bash script to backup a database and send it to another server, running the script on ssh (root) it sends the file correctly, but when using cPanel cron, i got this error:

*cd: Fatal error: pseudo-tty allocation failed: No such file or directory*

*put: Fatal error: pseudo-tty allocation failed: No such file or directory*

It looks like to fail on lftp changing to *uploads* folder

**Cron**

```
/bin/sh /home/test/backup/script.sh >> /home/test/backup/log.txt 2>&1
```

**Bash**

```
/bin/lftp sftp://user:pass@domain.com:22/uploads -e "put $FILE2; bye"
```

Comment: How do you login via SFTP? using ssh key or password?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your issue is this: You are logging in via SFTP using a ssh key (otherwise every time you try to sftp you would normally be required to enter a password and that will mess the cron). Probably you have the ssh key saved under the user root but when you execute the cron, it executes as a cpanel user (unless you executed directly in the root crontab). If executed as a cpanel user, and that user doesn't have the ssh key, then the cron hangs asking for the sftp password. Please be sure that the ssh private key used to SFTP as root is also added to the cpanel user's account under which the cron is executed. It should work then